# How assign a name to an SQLite In Memory Database

Tags: sqlite, in-memory-database

Refer to the code below

```
sqlite3 * db1;
sqlite3 * db2;
sqlite3_open("file:db1?mode=memory?cache=shared", &db1);
sqlite3_open("file:db2?mode=memory?cache=shared", &db2);
sqlite3_exec(db1, "create table t1 (a int)", NULL, NULL, NULL);
sqlite3_exec(db2, "create table t2 (a int)", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Is it possible to assign a name to db1, e.g. "db1", and to db2, e.g. "db2" so that I can do

```
sqlite3_exec(db1, "select * from db1.t1 inner join db2.t2 on db1.t1.a = db2.t2.a", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to attach the database [see](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_attach_database.htm)